# какой смысл аргументов?

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Какой смысл указанных аргументов функции?

Comment: хм... а какой смысл передачи параметров в программу?

Comment: Интересно, скоро ли появится вопрос вида *"для чего нужна функция `main`"*.

Answer (score 2):

Общий смысл аргументов - это задавать программе аргументы через командную строку при запуске программы.

В этом объявлении

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

параметр `argc` указывает общее число аргументов, переданных программе при ее запуске, а массив `argv` - указатели на строковые представления аргументов. Если `argc` не равен 0, то `argv[0]` задает либо имя зап3ускаемой программы, либо, если среда не передает программе в качестве параметра имя программы, то пустая строка `""`. Значение `argv[argc]` всегда равно 0.

Вы можете использовать любые имена вместо `argc` и `argv` по своему усмотрению.

Распечатать переданные в вашу программу аргументы можно различными способами. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    for ( char **p = argv; *p; ++p ) std::cout << *p << std::endl;  
}
```

Если ваша программа не нуждается ни в каких аргументах, переданных ей при запуске, то вы можете объявить функцию main как

```
int main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`argc` - количество элементов в массиве `argv`.

`argv` - массив строк-параметров, переданных в командной строке.

```
prog.exe first second third

agrv[0] - имя файла prog.exe
argv[1] - first
argv[2] - second
argv[3] - third
```

Некоторые операционки (и сами программы) могут обрабатывать параметры - например, соединяя в один параметр то, что в кавычках, или заменяя шаблон типа * на список имен файлов, отвечающий шаблону, но это уже другой вопрос...

Comment: argv[0] далеко не всегда содержит имя программы в винде, если на него опираться - может очень весело выйти...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Кстати, реально - где и когда такое наблюдается? Хотя да, такое пишут и предупреждают - пока *реально* ни разу не сталкивался. Ну, разве что специально в `spawn...` передать какую-то ерунду, и то - именно ерунду, а не нулевой указатель - иначе `spawn...` сыпется (VC++, тот же Open Watcom все равно передаст правильное имя, что бы не ввести в качестве `argv[0]`). Но, раз вы написали - "далеко не всегда" - то где это встречается в реальном, так сказать, мире, а не в специально созданном для этого коде?

Comment: @Harry: Легко, запускаете программу при помощи [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) и передаёте любую ерунду в `lpCommandLine`.

Comment: @Harry: А в реальном мире это встречается, если ваш код выполняется во враждебном окружении, и вы рассчитываете на значение `argv[0]` для всяких штук, связанных с безопасностью. Например, по имени программы ищете имя файла с настройками.

Comment: @VladD Т.е. это в любом случае делается преднамеренно, а не потому, что так сделано в данной ОС/компиляторе/etc... Q.E.D.

Comment: @Harry: Ну, это значит, что это не гарантируется рантаймом. Например, то, что финальный аргумент есть NULL, рантайм обеспечивает (что бы там ни делало враждебное окружение), и на это можно рассчитывать. А вот то, что нулевой аргумент содержит имя программы, рантайм не гарантирует, и рассчитывать на это нельзя.